# Can I insert tabs in quotations? Design/Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, page-layout

Here's a picture showing what I mean. [image: The tab I refer is the one in the first line of the epigraph]

Is it correct to tab quotations such as did here?

Thank you!

Comment: What I mean is: In design in general is it normal to have tabs/indents in quotations? Because I haven't seen it in books, so I'm wondering

Comment: That's what you would call a Blockquote and it's perfectly fine to do.  Maybe not in novels, but I see it frequently in publications and on the web.

Comment: @JohnManly please leave it as an actual answer so people can vote and comment and hopefully accept it

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is called a block quotation, typically "block quote" and is often used in print and web use.

Though I've used them many times myself, I feel [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_quotation) does a better job of explaining than I do. By the way, the formatting of the excerpt below is an example of a block quote:

> ...a quotation in a written document, that is set off from the main text as a paragraph, or block of text, and typically distinguished visually using indentation and a different typeface or smaller size font...

The standards for when and how to use block quotes will depend on which (if any) style manual you are trying to adhere to (MLA, APA, Chicago, etc.). If this is not a professional publication that needs to conform to a standard, then there aren't really any hard-set rules, other than the elimination of quotation marks and indenting the entire block from the body text.

If you are referring to the indentation of the first line *within* the block quote itself then no, don't do that.